# Como faço para o valor do meu input aparecer em uma div ou <p> como number. Mas não aparece nada. Quando aparece é NaN

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="container">
        <p id="p"></p>
        <input type="number" id="inputsaldo" value min="0" placeholder="" maxlength="10" required>
        <button id="btncheck"><i class="fas fa-grin-tongue-wink"></i></button>
</div>

<script>
let inputsaldo = parseFloat(document.getElementById('inputsaldo').value)
let button = document.getElementById('btncheck')
var p = document.getElementById('p').innerHTML 

console.log(typeof inputsaldo)

button.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    p = 'saldo: ' + inputsaldo;
});
</script>
```

Comment: Caso, qualquer uma das respostas abaixo resolveu seu problema marque como aceita.

Answer (score 1):

alguns conceitos que te estão a falhar:

- `let inputsaldo`: da maneira como estás a usar esse valor é lido imediatamente quando a página carrega. Penso que o que queres é ler o valor quando o botão for clicado. Muda essa linha para dentro da callback do `addEventListener`.
- `var p`:  quando essa linha corre o `p` fica com o valor do html desse elemento. Não uma referência para poderes escrever dentro do `p` mas sim o seu valor imediato quando o código é iniciado.

Sugiro que mudes para:

```html
<div class="container">
  <p id="p"></p>
  <input type="number" id="inputsaldo" value min="0" placeholder="" maxlength="10" required>
  <button id="btncheck"><i class="fas fa-grin-tongue-wink">Verificar</i></button>
</div>

<script>
  const button = document.getElementById('btncheck')
  const p = document.getElementById('p');

  console.log(typeof inputsaldo)

  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const inputsaldo = parseFloat(document.getElementById('inputsaldo').value)

    p.innerHTML = 'saldo: ' + inputsaldo;
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

No seu código *Javascript* necessita de algumas observações, o *JavaScript* é executado de "cima para baixo quando a página for carregada", no caso do seu código na seguinte linha:

```
let inputsaldo = parseFloat(document.getElementById('inputsaldo').value)
```

Essa linha já é executada logo quando a página for carregada, seu objetivo não é pegar uma referência do elemento `<input id="inputsaldo">` e armazenar na variável `inputsaldo` logo quando a página for carregada, creio que seu objetivo é fazer isso quando for clicado no elemento `<button id="btncheck">`, então ele deve estar dentro da função *Arrow Function* que está sendo chamada no evento de `click`.

```
var p = document.getElementById('p').innerHTML
```

Na linha acima a variável `p` está armazenando um valor como `<p id="p">testando</p>` e quando for clicado no botão os dados serão sobrescritos para `'saldo: ' + inputsaldo` o que você precisa é de uma referência para poder escrever dentro do elemento `<p id="p"></p>` que no caso usando o `innerHTML` quando o botão for clicado:

```
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
   p.innerHTML = 'saldo: ' + inputsaldo;
});
```

No caso o código ficaria assim para poder funcionar:

**Resultado**

```html
<div class="container">
    <p id="p"></p>
    <input type="number" id="inputsaldo" value min="0" placeholder="" maxlength="10" required>
    <button id="btncheck"><i class="fas fa-grin-tongue-wink"></i></button>
</div>

<script>
    let button = document.getElementById('btncheck')
    var p = document.getElementById('p');
    
    console.log(typeof inputsaldo)
    
    button.addEventListener('click', () =>{
        let inputsaldo = parseFloat(document.getElementById('inputsaldo').value)
        p.innerHTML = 'saldo: ' + inputsaldo;
    });
</script>
```